# Regression vs Classifier predict_proba

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, regression

Just a quick question, if I want to classify objects into either 0 or 1 but I would like the model to return me a 'likeliness' probability for example if an object is 0.7, it means it has 0.7 chance of being in class 1, do I do a regression or stick to classifiers and use the predict_proba function?

How is regression and predict_proba function different?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Regression (e.g. some linear function of a feature vector) gives a continuous value that is related with the posterior probability via logistic sigmoid function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, **for a qualitative problem** that is to classify between categories or class, we prefer classification.

> for example: to identify if it is night or day.

**For Quantitative problems**, we prefer regression to solve the problems.

> for example: to identify if its 0th class or 1st class.

But in a special case, when we have only two classes. Then, we can use both classification and regression to solve two-class problems as in your case.

Please note that, this explanation is on the behalf of two-class point of view or multi-class problems. Though regression is to deal with real quantitative problems rather than classes.

Probability has nothing to deal specifically with methods. Each method deduce a probability and on the basis of that, they predict the outcome.

> It is better if you explain the reference to `predict_proba` from your
>   question.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

Since you mention the `predict_proba`function I'm assuming you are referring to the scikit-learn API.

To obtain class-membership probailities this is the right function. In the case of logistic regression, this function is somehow the natural output.

You should also check [probability calibration](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html)